# htaccess 301 redirect to home/index page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need the solution for home page 301 redirection.

If I enter like below url in the browse bar

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/component/restaurantguide/tags/tags/2-kebab?sem_midx=-3&sem_jidx=-1

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/about-us/restaurant/faq.php

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/about-us/tags/18-pizzeria

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/about-us/tags/9-online-shop

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/tilfoj-din-butik/city/47-odder?sem_midx=-1&sem_jidx=-3&format=feed&type=atom

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/component/restaurantguide/recipes/recipes/20-ca-nuong-trui-bare-fried-fish?sem_midx=3&sem_jidx=1

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/tilfoj-din-butik/city/95-kalundborg?sem_midx=-6&sem_jidx=0

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/component/restaurantguide/restaurant/1-frederiks-have?sem_midx=2&sem_jidx=1

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php/tilfoj-din-butik/tags/faq.php

http://www.starmed.dk/?index%5c.php%25253Fid=3-yorkshire-savings-account.83&xzaty=3&article=83

http://www.starmed.dk/?option=com_restaurantguide&view=states&id=450:midtjylland

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php?cPath=56

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php?cPath=25

http://www.starmed.dk/index.php?cPath=47
and etc...

If I enter after index.php some values like mentoned above example

then it will be redirected to http://www.starmed.dk without index.php

How to do this using HTACCESS 301 redirect common rule?

Comment: If it is already redirecting to `http://www.starmed.dk` then why do you need this additional 301 rule?

Comment: I've redirected using php, but i need to do using .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to remove `index.php` from your URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php, MAKE SURE THIS IS YOUR FIRST RULE
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```